# Command not found, even though it is installed on debian

Tags: bash, debian, mbr, package-management

```
# mbr-install
bash: mbr-install: command not found
# apt install mbr-install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package mbr-install
# mbr
bash: mbr: command not found
# apt install mbr
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
mbr is already the newest version (1.2.1).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 21 not upgraded.
# mbr
bash: mbr: command not found
```

I do not get it. I have the package `mbr` (which is also package for `mbr-install`) installed, but when I try to execute it. Then bash cannot find it.

`# echo $PATH`

`/home/user123/perl5/bin:/sbin:/home/user123/Desktop/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games`

There is `/sbin` in which it should be installed. Does anyone know, why the command is not found, even thought the package is installed?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend this process (I guess you do this with root, right?):
Step 1: check whether the executable exists on your filesystem. Use `updatedb` to update the location database, then execute `locate mbr`
Step 2: After you found it, try starting it by using its full path. If you get denied, the error will show you what is wrong.

Comment: sorry, but did not helped. The `mbr` is not located in "normal" bin dirs, but rather here `/usr/lib/syslinux/mbr`, what is strange though, is I cannot man-page it (becuase the `man mbr -> command not found`), even when it is in `/usr/share/doc/mbr`

Comment: Well, the process should have brought another file to your attention: `/sbin/install-mbr`. It is probably what you are looking for, but you had it wrongly named so far.